# Triggering method

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Maybe someone knows when `def _compute_amounts_in_user_currency(self)`: is triggered? it's in `_name = "account.invoice.report"` model. can't make this method start calculations. In Business Intelligence report I have bad calculations so need to check how this method is calculating `user_currency_price_total` field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method `_compute_amounts_in_user_currency` is triggered when you access to the fields that it computes: `user_currency_price_total`, `user_currency_price_average` and `user_currency_residual`.

All the access call to the value of any of those fields will trigger the method call one time per record in order to compute and retrieve the their values.

The records in this case came from a complex sql view. I suggest you to check also for the defined currency rates between your company system currency and the default system EUR currency that could be leading to the bad calculations